# MCMCpack not saving scores

Tags: r, mcmc

I am using MCMCmixfactanal to measure latent factor variable, and it requires to set store.scores=TRUE to save phi which is required to estimate latent factor variable. But I have large dataset and I cannot save all the scores because of the quantity. Is there a way to save the mean of scores instead of saving all of them?

Comment: Are you running out of memory during the MCMC run itself? I don't see a way to pass arguments to the function to convince it to do this, but could show you how to hack the R code so that it collapsed the scores to mean values before returning the output. However, the full matrix would still be returned from the C code (which would be harder to hack), so if you simply have insufficient memory to store this information even temporarily then that won't help you ...

Comment: It seems like the problem is after running MCMC model as I can estimate acceptance rate for the model and then show the error message that it cannot allocate the vector size of too large. I would appreciate to get any help with around this problem.

Comment: Can you use `traceback()` to find the exact point at which your code fails?

Comment: it will take a while but I will try and make a comment.